# WidgetContainer displaying dropdown menu in wrong place

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a problem with the `xe:widgetContainer` on my notes 9 server. Instead of displaying the dropdown menu on the right side it sticks it next to the container header. I already found the style that is causing the issue:

```
.xsp .lotusSection2 .lotusSectionHeader {
    display: block
    width: 100%;
  }
```

which overwrites the style:

```
.lotusui30 .lotusSection2 .lotusSectionHeader {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The new style is located in the `oneui302xsp.css` which seems to get included by the extension library. I tested the same xPage which does only contain a widgetContainer on my local computer which runs an older version of the extension library and I found out that the `oneui302xsp.css` is missing and the dropdown menu is displayed in the right place.

So my question is:
Instead of overwriting the style again I just want to remove the cssinclude of `oneui302xsp.css` created by the extension library. My current extlib version is 901v00_04.20140226-1506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css you've highlighted that is causing this issue was added to fix another reported issue. But, as you've highlighted, that fix has inadvertently caused an issue with the dropdown menu. I can investigate a fix that will resolve this new issue, whilst preserving the fix for the previous issue. And hopefully get this into the next extension library release on OpenNTF.

At a glance, a work-around you could try is adding the following css to your app (although I haven't tested it thoroughly):

```
.xsp .lotusSection2 .lotusSectionHeader .lotusInner h2{width:100%;}
```

The file oneui302xsp.css was added in release 901_v02 of the 901 extlib I believe. It contains a number of styling fixes for the OneUI v3.0.2 theme in XPages, so we wouldn't recommend trying to disable it entirely. If you have found other issues with the oneui302 theme, then feel free to report them on the OpenNTF forum. I've responded to your post on OpenNTF and included my email in the reply if you want to forward us any issues.